# Pack on Mac fails to connect to docker via socket (yet docker CLI works just fine)

Tags: docker, macos

Trying to run `pack` to build a Cloud Native Buildpack on Mac, it fails, complaining about not finding the expected Docker socket, where it usually is:

```
pack build my-app --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
ERROR: failed to build: failed to fetch builder image 'index.docker.io/paketobuildpacks/builder:base': 
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. 
Is the docker daemon running?
```

But all docker CLI commands such as `docker ps` work just fine. I am running Docker Desktop for Mac.

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation

The problem turns out to be that Docker Desktop uses a different socket. It works because the docker CLI is set automatically to use the correct "context"). See:

I too am running into this problem (with Docker Desktop for Mac), where `pack build ...` fails to connect b/c I have no `/var/run/docker.sock` - but the `docker` CLI itself works just fine. Thhe docker context explains why it is the case:

```bash
$ docker context list
NAME                TYPE                DESCRIPTION                               DOCKER ENDPOINT                                 KUBERNETES ENDPOINT                                 ORCHESTRATOR
default             moby                Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock                     https://kubernetes.docker.internal:6443 (default)   swarm
desktop-linux *     moby                                                          unix:///Users/me/.docker/run/docker.sock

$ docker context show
desktop-linux
```

so the `default` context uses the standard socket but is not active and the socket does not exist. Instead, the active context is `desktop-linux`, which uses a socket in the user's home dir (which does exist).

There is an open (3/2023) [pack issue to use docker context](https://github.com/buildpacks/pack/issues/1346) to get the correct host automatically.

### Solution

The solution then is to point pack to the correct socket:

```bash
env DOCKER_HOST=unix:///Users/me/.docker/run/docker.sock pack build my-app \
  --builder paketobuildpacks/builder:base
```

Answer (score 0):

To permanently fix the issue

`echo export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///Users/kiplangatvictor/.docker/run/docker.sock >> ~/.zshrc`

replace the .zsshrc with your respective file

Comment: Though this will only work until the docker context is changed...